# Replacement for disable-validation-message in Angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I'm not sure `disable-validation-message` does what I want but I found it to be close enough.

Basically I'm looking for a way to prevent angular from setting errors on a `Control` input defined by `formBuilder` and use `maxlength` as well.

```ts
<input type="text" ngControl="foo" maxlength="500" />
```

Comment: You mean the `ng-xxx` classes should not be added to the elements? What's the problem with them?

Comment: `ng-xxx` classes are targeted by css, I just don't want error messages in `control.errors`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

```
const DUMMY_MAX_LENGTH_VALIDATOR = CONST_EXPR(
new Provider(NG_VALIDATORS, {useExisting: forwardRef(() => DummyMaxLengthValidatorr), multi: true}));

@Directive({
  selector: '[maxlength][ngControl],[maxlength][ngFormControl],[maxlength][ngModel]',
})
export class DummyMaxLengthValidator {
  validate(control) {}
}
```

than at your component add

```
@Component({
  ...
  providers: [DUMMY_MAX_LENGTH_VALIDATOR]
})
```

**original**

This might work but is likely to break eventually

```
<input type="text" ngControl="foo" [attr.maxlength]="'500'" />
```

AFAIK currently `maxlength` is read by `constructor(@Attribute('maxlength') ...)` which only passes static values. Making it a bound value might be able to work around. Besides that, the validators are applied for the `[ngControl][maxlength]` selector.

Comment: I get this `Can't bind to 'maxlength' since it isn't a known native property`

Comment: Right, should be `[attr.maxlength]`

Comment: this works, **original** is enough. Thanks for helping me fool angular's selector. ;)